# REMOTE_EXEC_OUTPUT_MARKER_ build.txt doesn't exist

Tags: linux, bash, amazon-ec2, phpstorm

This PhpStorm 2022.2.1 issue may happen when you are trying to Download your IDE after assertively pointing the Installer the remote development server project folder.

I can see the remove folder is recognized, the SSH connection is OK, but it suddenly stops to work and displays the following log. The above-mentioned `build.txt` can't be found, as it can be seen at the last line:

```
[ip here] :: uname -sm :: exit
code: 0 :: stdout: Linux x86_64 :: stderr: 
[ip here] :: uname -sm :: exit code: 0 :: stdout: Linux x86_64 :: stderr: 
[ip here] :: echo $HOME :: exit code: 0 :: stdout: /home/ec2-user :: stderr: 
[ip here] :: test -f /home/ec2-user/.cache/JetBrains/RemoteDev/remote-dev-worker/remote-dev-worker_8be48ed1f7d9d149a663842f0df2735b7433265d1654774596e54ce70af850f2 :: exit code: 0 :: stdout:  :: stderr: 
[ip here] :: test -x /home/ec2-user/.cache/JetBrains/RemoteDev/remote-dev-worker/remote-dev-worker_8be48ed1f7d9d149a663842f0df2735b7433265d1654774596e54ce70af850f2 :: exit code: 0 :: stdout:  :: stderr: 
[ip here] :: echo $SHELL :: exit code: 0 :: stdout: /bin/bash :: stderr: 
[ip here] :: /bin/bash -lc echo\ REMOTE_EXEC_OUTPUT_MARKER_\ \&\&\ /home/ec2-user/.cache/JetBrains/RemoteDev/remote-dev-worker/remote-dev-worker_8be48ed1f7d9d149a663842f0df2735b7433265d1654774596e54ce70af850f2\ exists\ --path=/home/ec2-user/.cache/JetBrains/RemoteDev/dist/d230e8fa76ec0_PhpStorm-222.4167.9/.expandSucceeded\ --file=true :: exit code: 0 :: stdout: REMOTE_EXEC_OUTPUT_MARKER_
false :: stderr: 
[ip here] :: /bin/bash -lc echo\ REMOTE_EXEC_OUTPUT_MARKER_\ \&\&\ /home/ec2-user/.cache/JetBrains/RemoteDev/remote-dev-worker/remote-dev-worker_8be48ed1f7d9d149a663842f0df2735b7433265d1654774596e54ce70af850f2\ create-dir\ --path=/home/ec2-user/.cache/JetBrains/RemoteDev/dist/d230e8fa76ec0_PhpStorm-222.4167.9 :: exit code: 0 :: stdout: REMOTE_EXEC_OUTPUT_MARKER_ :: stderr: 
[ip here] :: /bin/bash -lc echo\ REMOTE_EXEC_OUTPUT_MARKER_\ \&\&\ /home/ec2-user/.cache/JetBrains/RemoteDev/remote-dev-worker/remote-dev-worker_8be48ed1f7d9d149a663842f0df2735b7433265d1654774596e54ce70af850f2\ available-space\ --path=/home/ec2-user/.cache/JetBrains/RemoteDev/dist/d230e8fa76ec0_PhpStorm-222.4167.9 :: exit code: 0 :: stdout: REMOTE_EXEC_OUTPUT_MARKER_
2790494208 :: stderr: 
[ip here] :: /bin/bash -lc echo\ REMOTE_EXEC_OUTPUT_MARKER_\ \&\&\ /home/ec2-user/.cache/JetBrains/RemoteDev/remote-dev-worker/remote-dev-worker_8be48ed1f7d9d149a663842f0df2735b7433265d1654774596e54ce70af850f2\ product-code\ --ide-path=/home/ec2-user/.cache/JetBrains/RemoteDev/dist/d230e8fa76ec0_PhpStorm-222.4167.9 :: exit code: 1 :: stdout: REMOTE_EXEC_OUTPUT_MARKER_
{"type":"error","errorCode":"CommandError","data":"/home/ec2-user/.cache/JetBrains/RemoteDev/dist/d230e8fa76ec0_PhpStorm-222.4167.9/build.txt doesn't exist"} :: stderr:
```

In fact this file doesn't exist, and I even tried `touch build.txt` at this `/home/ec2-user/.cache/JetBrains/RemoteDev/dist/d230e8fa76ec0_PhpStorm-222.4167.9/` but then it can't be parsed and a corresponding error emerges.

This same issue was open here: https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/WI-68709/REMOTEEXECOUTPUTMARKER-buildtxt-doesnt-exist

Answer (score 0):

This problem occurs because of a reason that prevented the IDE of being downloaded on the server.
In the link you provided it is said that it may be because of a low bandwidth but there could be more reasons.
In my case I had this problem because of a lack of space on server. The IDE requires at least 4GB of empty space to be downloaded.